# Загрузка фотографий в БД и вывод на страницу Flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask, jinja2

**Доброго времени суток**

У меня вопрос касаемо Flask разработки, а именно работа с базой данных.
Как можно загрузить фотографии ***(несколько)*** в базу данных, и выводить их под своей записью.

Пример:
Фото
Название
Описание

И таких несколько записей. Целый день голову морочу ничего толкового найти не могу.

Comment: Сами фотографии в базу данных сохранять не стоит. А вот пути к файлам в static директории, или в cdn - обычно так делают.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, но не через БД, а через папки, сделал проще: создавалась папка (название: айдишник записи) и туда закидывалась фотография, затем просто оттуда выводил фото, все сработало.